# How can I find 3 or more elements of same class in adjacent?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a candy crush game with buttons as candies. I have been able to lay the grid of candies (buttons) with each button assigned to random color class (among given 4). This is shown in the image below:

[image: Candy/button grid]

How can I detect the candies (3/more) of same color class vertically/horizontally adjacent

I don't know much but I am guessing the number of adjacent candies should be detected by a frame (horizontal/vertical) and the frame size should decrease from max (6) to (3) in each round of detection. Of course if size 3 frame can't detect alignment, there is no need to use frame sized 2,1.

```js
//var candyType=4;
var moves = 20;
const colors = Array('green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red');

function play() {
  const candy = document.querySelectorAll("button");

  //document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = candy.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < candy.length; i++) {
    // if(colors[i]){
    const randomColor =
      colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    candy[i].className = randomColor;
  }
}
if (moves >= 0) {
  document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = moves;
  max_frame = 6
} else {
  alert("GAME OVER");
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.game {
  width: 375px;
  height: 510px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Candy-crush</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body onload="play()">

  <p>Moves: </p>
  <p id="moves"></p>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="panel">
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, pls provide your html code to get to know dom structure

Comment: without knowing how you set up your grid, it's hard to help you... show some code :)

Comment: interesting problem, i'll get back to it when i am home ;)